# Initialize Spring beans when running Jersey test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jersey-2.0, spring-annotations

I am using latest Spring and Jersey Test framework.
All my resources use Jersey.

I have spring beans which are being initialized by @Service annotation. 
Each service register itself to a customer ServiceContainer which is a bean singletone.

In my resource I am fetching the service from the container and using annotations.
I am running Unit test using Jersey framework. How can I initialize those services with annotations of @Service. I am not using the @Autowire / @Inject annotations in my resources.

I took a look on couple of similar cases but nothing was helpful, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

```
    @Override
protected DeploymentContext configureDeployment() {
    ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();
    config.packages("com.my.application");
    return ServletDeploymentContext
            .forServlet(new ServletContainer(config))
            .addListener(ContextLoaderListener.class)
            .contextParam("contextConfigLocation", "classpath:applicationContext.xml")
            .build();

}
```